# Is there a way to write `$this->` quickly in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

PHP uses a `this` syntax that is kind of hard to write (three special characters, two of them with modifiers on a typical US keyboard layout). I am using PhpStorm and am wondering if there isn't a way to get to this state:

```
$this->{cursor}
```

faster than after typing 7 characters.

Comment: A live template. ex http://i.imgur.com/4bs58GL.png - Type `sthi<tab>` and you get $this->

Comment: @MikeB Too long. I have 2 (but they do the same job): `t` and `$t`

Comment: Good suggestions guys. @LazyOne make that an answer and I'll mark it as such :)

Comment: I was not the first who suggested it... :)